# Windows Phone App Exit Notification

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

[image: Exit Notifier]

I saw this really cool feature in a app. Currently I am showing MessageBox to ask if User wants to exit app. But as shown in Image this ExitNotification comes at the top of page like a Push Notification and if User presses back button once more the app exits.
Please help me how can i create similar notification. Thanks.

Comment: Is my answer helpful or not..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Control is [ToastPrompt](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-toast-prompt-in-depth) from Coding4fun toolkit. To begin using ToastPrompt first add a reference to  the `Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.dll` assembly.

After that create `ToastPrrompt` like this in method `OnBackKeyPress` from [Here](http://www.programering.com/a/MjM1kTMwATA.html)

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isExit)
        {
            isExit = true;
            var toast = new ToastPrompt();
            toast.Message = "Press back again to exit?";
            toast.MillisecondsUntilHidden = 3000;
            toast.Completed += (o, ex) => { isExit = false; };
            toast.Show();
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        }
    }
```

Note : You have to create `bool variable as isExit` & MillisecondsUntilHidden is count of time to display popup in millseconds.

Thanks to Coding4Fun guys

Comment: if u want to terminate when 2nd time back button is pressed , write **Application.Current.Terminate();** before NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();

Answer (score 2):

for achieving this you can use `PopUp` Control. You can show popup on the top of `LayoutRoot` Grid of the Application Page. For Creating PopUp you can have Reference from here [How to use Pop-Ups in Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Pop-Ups_in_Windows_Phone)